# Python read JSON from named pipe/FIFO

Tags: python, json, named-pipes, mkfifo

I'm trying to read JSON data from a FIFO as in the code below:

```py
import os
import errno
import json

FIFO = '/tmp/vision'

try:
    os.mkfifo(FIFO)
except OSError as oe: 
    if oe.errno != errno.EEXIST:
        raise

print("Opening FIFO...")
while True:
    with open(FIFO) as fifo:
        for line in fifo:
            #line = '{"humans": []}' # WORKS FINE
            print(line)
            perception_output = json.loads(line)
            print(perception_output)
            print(type(perception_output))
```

I'm constantly pushing on the other side (C++ code) of the FIFO one-line JSONs. The delimiter is "\n". The strange thing is that I can successfully load the **first line** and print it as Python dictionary as in the log below, but on the **second line** I observe the following error:

```sh
me@pc:~/vision$ python3 brain.py 
Opening FIFO...
{ "humans": [ ] }

{'humans': []}
<class 'dict'>
{ "humans": [ ] }

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "brain1.py", line 19, in <module>
    perception_output = json.loads(line)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

If I hardcode the "line" variable as commented I have no issues. What could be the problem?

Edit: Adding the C++ code of the FIFO Writer:

```cpp
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int fd;
    const char * myfifo = "/tmp/vision";
    fd = open(myfifo, O_WRONLY);

    if (fd <= 0) {
        throw std::logic_error("Cannot open FIFO fd");
    }

    while (true) {
        std::string json_out = "{ \"humans\": [ ] }\n";
        std::cout << json_out << std::endl;

        if (write(fd, json_out.c_str(), strlen(json_out.c_str()) + 1) < 0) 
        {
            throw std::logic_error("Cannot write to FIFO fd");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please can you share [MWE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_working_example#:~:text=In%20computing%2C%20a%20minimal%20working,to%20be%20demonstrated%20and%20reproduced.&text=A%20minimal%20working%20example%20may,short%20self-contained%20correct%20example.)

Comment: @Chandan, I've added the C++ code of the writer.

Comment: Okay, I'm dumb :D Thank you @freakish!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`strlen(json_out.c_str()) + 1)` is your culprit. You should do `strlen(json_out.c_str())` or even better `json_out.length()`. The last element of every c string is the invisible `\0` char which you then send to the server's side. And that `\0` char then becomes the first element of new line which json decoder doesn't understand.